# Flutter BLoC stream disposed with listview.builder

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am trying to use a listview.builder with a stream, but I keep getting the error "StateError (Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close)". If I remove the dispose the error goes away. I know the error is because dispose is being called before all the data is loaded in the builder, but I don't know how to prevent the issue.

I tried using the AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin, but this didn't help. If I use an inherited widget and get the data from another page instead of creating the BLoC in this page I don't get the error, but that doesn't seem like a clean way to do it if I don't actually need the inherited widget for anything but preventing this error.

I saw a suggestion to use a drain in the BLoC's dispose like:

```
void dispose() async {
  await _myStream.drain();
  _myStream.close();
}
```

but also had no success with this.

Below is the code I am having the issue with, the issue occurs with the postBloc.post stream builder:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
    PostBloc postBloc;

    @override
    void initState() {
      postBloc = PostBloc();
      super.initState();
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
      postBloc.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        endDrawer: AppDrawer(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: postBloc.isPostLoading,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else {
              postBloc.refreshPostsIfNeeded();
              return StreamBuilder<UnmodifiableListView<Post>>(
                stream: postBloc.posts,
                initialData: UnmodifiableListView<Post>([]),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<UnmodifiableListView<Post>> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                        snapshot.data.map((data) => _buildPosts(context, data, postBloc)).toList()[index],
                    );
                  }
                }
              );
            }
          }
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face same problem.
Reluctantly, I use stream property `isClosed` and, if it is true, I do nothing.